# compatibility Query for to_number()

Tags: mysql, oracle

In this query using `to_number()` in oracle. How to write compatibility query for oracle and mysql databases.

```
SELECT col1 FROM table WHERE condition ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(col2);
```

Here `col2` is `varchar2` datatype. Suppose i was used `ORDER BY` command in this query must use converting function i.e `to_number(col2)`,this function not available in mysql.so please give correct solution for above problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a custom function in your mysql db with name `to_number` which takes same parameter and returns integer .
You can then use `cast` function inside your custom function

`DELIMITER $$`
`DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS to_number$$`
`CREATE  FUNCTION to_number (number VARCHAR(10)) RETURNS INT (11)`
`BEGIN`
`RETURN (CAST(number AS SIGNED));`
`END$$`
`DELIMITER ;`

This will create a custom/userdefined function with to_number as name
Then you can use your query both in oracle and mysql

Comment: how to create custom function in mysql and oracle.i want writer same query for both database.Please explain briefly

Comment: Edited my answer with explanation

Comment: Akil please reply where i create above function..i am using Windows XP,sqlyog tool for mysql,toad tool for oracle.

Comment: Create it in mysql through sqlyog tool. Just copy paste this in sqlyog query editor and execute

Comment: i copied into both editor. Mysql only working properly. Oracle throws an errors invalid sql statement. How i use this function in myprogram instead of query.

Comment: You need not run in oracle. It has the function to_number as an inbuilt function <br> you need to execute this only in mysql through sqlyog and the original query will work in both mysql and oracle

Comment: Thanks for valuable information.It works Perfectly in both Database

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with CAST

```
select id,num type, details,CAST(num AS SIGNED) as T 
from demo order by T
```

SQL Fiddle [link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/702a7/3)

For more info : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html

Comment: SELECT * FROM COMMBRANCH ORDER BY CAST(MBRNORDERNO AS SIGNED) this query was working in mysql.but doesn't worked in oracle.Because SIGNED is invalid datatype.it throws errors. Tell another Possible